# Vue.js error 6:1 error Prefer default export import/prefer-default-export

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I started vuex study and i have an error in Vue.js/Vuex-store:   6:1  error  Prefer default export  import/prefer-default-export;
The error telling me that i have to change export const store to export default and i don't want it

I can't fix and help please;

```js
// Vuex store
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
  },
  getters: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.count += 1;
    },
  },
});


// main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { store } from './Vuex-store/store.js';

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
  store,
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ this.$store.state.count }}
    <button @click="increment">increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$store.getters.increment;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is just an eslint rule. It wants you to do a `default export` instead of `export const`:

Export it like this:

```js
export default store
```

Then, instead of importing like

```js
import { store } from './Vuex-store/store.js';
```

do just

```
import store from './Vuex-store/store.js';
```

Comment: it's don't working again error:   6:16  error  'store' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: could you show me the code somewhere? Which line is the throwing the error in which of the two files?

Comment: export default store

Comment: first set `const store = new Vue.Store({})`, then export this `store` variable using `export default store`

Answer (score 0):

### Try it

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ count }}
    <button @click="increment">increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  computed: {
    count() {
      return this.$store.state.count;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$store.getters.increment;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```